# Using insertion sorting to sort student names and their scores, structure array set as a pointer, and passing structure array pointer to functions

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, dynamic-arrays

I am trying to implement insertion sorting in my C++ program to sort both the names of students and their test scores in ascending order according to their test scores. The names and test scores are user defined. I get no errors as far as building my program. The program runs as well and calculates the average correctly, but the insertion sorting does not sort the information that is inputted by the user. I am using an array of structures set as a pointer which is dynamically allocated by the user to hold the information of each student and must use pointers rather than array indices. Any advice and help on fixing the insertion sorting of my program would be much appreciated. Also, I would like to know if i am utilizing my pointers and pointer notation correctly.

```
 struct Pair
    {

string names;

int testscores;

};

//Function prototypes//

void sorting(Pair*,int);
void Swap(int,int,string,string);
int getAVG(Pair*,int);


int main()
{    
   Pair *NS;
   int average, num_test;

cout<<"How many test scores would you like to enter? ";
cin>>num_test;

while(num_test<0||!cin)
{
    cout<<"**Invalid entry** Amount of test scores cannot be written/typed in letters.\nPlease enter valid amount of test scores: ";
    cin>>num_test;
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}

    if(num_test>0)
    {NS=new Pair[num_test];}

if (NS == NULL)
{
    cout<<"Memory allocation error.";
    exit(1);
}

for(int i=0;i<num_test;i++)
{ 
    cout<<"\nEnter name of student "<<i+1<< " and their test score:";
    cin>>(NS+i)->names>>(NS+i)->testscores;
    while((NS+i)->testscores<0 || !cin)
    {
        cout<<" **Invalid Entry**\n Test scores entered cannot be letters or negative numbers. Please enter valid test score.\n";
        cin>>(NS+i)->testscores;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(),'\n');
}
}

sorting(NS,num_test);

cout<<"\n**Test Scores in ascending order**\n\n";
for(int k=0; k<num_test; k++)
{
    cout<<(NS+k)->names<<": "<<(NS+k)->testscores<<"\n";
}
average=getAVG(NS,num_test);

cout<<"\n\nAverage test score: "<<average<<endl;

delete[] NS;
NS=0;

return 0;
}


//This is the sorting function and swap function portion of my program//

void sorting (Pair *s_ptr, int Length)

{
  int j;

for(int count=1; count <Length; count++)
{
    for(j=count; j>0 && ((s_ptr+j-1)->testscores)>((s_ptr+j)->testscores);j--)
    {
        Swap(((s_ptr+j-1)->testscores),((s_ptr+j)->testscores),((s_ptr+j-1)->names),((s_ptr+j)->names));
    }
}}

void Swap( int index1, int index2, string name1, string name2)

{

int temp=index1;
index1=index2;
index2=temp;
string N_temp=name1;
name1=name2;
name2=N_temp;
}
```

Comment: Your `Swap` function needs to take its parameters by reference.

Comment: As @JonathanPotter said your Swap needs to take parameters by reference. Read "Pass by Value vs. Pass by Reference".